# Errors installing composer on Windows

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm attempting to install Composer in order to install Laravel. Using the Windows installer the Composer website provides, I'm given the following errors after assigning the php.exe to the one in WAMP:

```
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I've also assigned system variables for PHP and Composer. What am I missing?

Comment: For future reference, it is easier to read questions when code sections are set off with code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into and SSL error when trying to install laravel on my windows machine for the first time as well.  I wrote these steps down at the time and saved them on my blog, the 2 that you need are copied below:

1.) Enable openSSL in wamp server (allows us to install composer which is step #2)

From the wamp tray icon hit php > php extensions > php_openSSL (note we also need both php_curl & php_socket enabled for later steps)
restart wamp server
navigate to and open (C:\wamp\bin\php\php-5.4.3\php.ini).  Search for openssl and remove the comment in front of the line (then save the file)
now were ready to install composer

2.) Install Composer.  On windows you can install composer by downloading this setup file (https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)

if you did not enable openssl correctly you will get the following error (The openssl extension is missing, which will reduce the security and stability of Composer. If possible you should enable it or recompile php with –with-openssl).  If you get this error go back and re-visit ((C:\wamp\bin\php\php-5.4.3\php.ini).  openSSL needs to be enabled in this file for composer to install
now open up the command prompt and navigate to the directory you will store laravel in and install composer.  e.x.  CD C:\wamp\www\laravel) then type “composer install”.  The install will run and provide you feedback on if it was successful or not.

Also you did not ask this but another helpful note I had was to get some features of laravel working correctly only windows you need to alter your environment variables:

3.) Add PHP to windows environment variables

start > environment variables for your account > Path > edit (now chose the path variable under “user variables”)
add (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12) so full line will look like: (C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Samuel. However, (and I didn't mention this) I have already performed those steps. php_openSSL, php_curl, and php_socket are all enabled. I've also created environment variables for php and composer which php doesn't work. While going through the steps of Composer-Setup.exe, the above error occurs. What steps do I need to take to recompile php with -with-openssl?